# Can you use CIDR on a Ubee DVW3201B?

Tags: networking

I'm configuring my new ISP-provided Ubee DVW3201B Home Gateway.  In doing this, I'd like to set up my own home network configuration which uses classless subnets.  (i.e.:  A subnet mask of 255.255.255.0 in 172.16.x.x IP space.)  However, I don't see any options in the LAN configuration which allow me to set a custom subnet mask.  Is this a feature not available on this device?  Does it default to classful subnet masks, or only use a /24 mask?

Sidenote:  If anyone's found a manual for this thing, please do share!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classful networking was already long gone by the time the web took off in the mid-1990's. By the time home gateways became a thing (as broadband ISPs came online in the late 1990's), they all did CIDR subnetting.

Most home gateways that don't show the subnet mask on the LAN side default to a /24, because that's more than enough host address space for a home network, and the vendor didn't want to waste resources supporting more hosts than that.

To confirm, see what subnet mask your gateway's DHCP server serves your your DHCP clients.

Comment: This home gateway does show the subnet mask, but does not allow changing it.  I've confirmed that it's stuck at /24 by changing the IP range to a different class.  Thanks for the info.